I get "Call to a member function setTimezone() on string" error after updating Laravel, how can I solve it?
I have this echo in my blade...
$sale->order_time->setTimezone($venue->timezone)

...and all I get is a "Call to a member function setTimezone() on string" error. This code used to work perfectly before updating Laravel.

Note that you should use ->getTimestamp() instead of strtotime() so to avoid useless cast to string.

And my boxers have holes but that's not the point but solving the error for anyone who has the same problem.

The way to declare a timestamp in models changed since Laravel 8. Update in your model from
protected $dates = ['order_time'];

To:
protected $casts = [
    'order_time' => 'datetime',
];

